# How to read multiple files from ftp server in java?

Tags: java, ftp

I have ftp server as follows

```
MainFolder 
 -Location1
   -download.txt
   -otherFiles...
 -Location2
   -download.txt
   -otherFiles...
 -Location3
   -download.txt
   -otherFiles...
 -LocationN
   -download.txt
   -otherFiles...
```

I want to read `download.txt` file from each Location folder and insert in db

I have written below code but it only reads `download.txt` file of `Location1` folders, it does not read other `download.txt` files from rest of the Location folders.

What's wrong with my code..?

Below is my code

```
public class ReadFtpFile {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReadFtpFile.class);
    public static String MAIN_FOLDER_PATH = "MAIN_FOLDER";
    public static String fileNameToBeRead = "download";


     public static void main(String[] args) {

      String ftpUrl = "10.x.x.x";  
      String user = "username";
      String pass = "password";

      FTPFile[] listOfFolders =null;
      int location = 0;
      FTPFile[] listOfFiles = null;

       // get an ftpClient object  
       FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();  


        // pass directory path on server to connect  
        ftpClient.connect(ftpUrl);  

        // pass username and password, returned true if authentication is successful  
        boolean login = ftpClient.login(user, pass); 

        FTPFileFilter filter = new FTPFileFilter() {
               @Override
               public boolean accept(FTPFile ftpFile) {
                  return (ftpFile.isFile() && ftpFile.getName().contains(fileNameToBeRead));
               }
        };


        if (login) {  
         logger.info("Connection established...");  

         FTPFile[] locationfolders = ftpClient.listDirectories(MAIN_FOLDER_PATH);  

         for (FTPFile folder : locationfolders) {  

          if(folder.isDirectory()){
              logger.info("Folder Found : "  + folder.getName());
              String subFolder = MAIN_FOLDER_PATH + "/" +folder.getName();
              FTPFile[] subfiles = ftpClient.listFiles(subFolder,filter); 
              for(FTPFile myfile : subfiles){
                  logger.info("File Name: "  + myfile.getName());
                  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(subFolder+ "/" +myfile.getName())));
                  logger.info("Reading file start.");

                  String inputLine;
                  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                   // logger.info(inputLine);
                  }
                  in.close();
                  logger.info("File Reading Completed");
              }
          }

         } 

         // logout the user, returned true if logout successfully  
         boolean logout = ftpClient.logout();  
         if (logout) {  
          logger.info("Connection close...");  
         }  
        } else {  
         logger.info("Connection fail...");  
        }     
     }
    }
```

OUTPUT :

```
Connection established...
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:74 - Folder Found : Location1
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:78 - File Name: download.txt
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:80 - Reading file start.
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:87 - File Reading Completed
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:74 - Folder Found : Location2
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:74 - Folder Found : Location3
22-05-2017 10:54:49 INFO  ReadFtpFile:74 - Folder Found : LocationN
```

Comment: Define 'does not read'. What does it do instead?

Comment: @EJP I have updated question. It just reads first file download.txt and does not reading other

Comment: You are just checking one folder and coming out of if statement. You need to loop through all folders before you come out of if statement.

Comment: @Amarnath I am looping through subFolder as well where I am comming out of if statement?

Comment: Ohh my bad. You are looping.. sorry missed the for loop on top.

Comment: What is the value of the `MAIN_FOLDER_PATH`?

Comment: @Martin MAIN_FOLDER_PATH value is ftp://10.x.x.x/MainFolder. Basically there server is Windows Server and they have given ftp access to  D:/MainFolder

Comment: That's not a path, that's a URL. Try `/MainFolder`

Comment: @Martin still same output is comming

Comment: So start with the code suggested by @JKnight. See if it downloads all files from all folders.

Comment: So how many elements were there in `locationfolders`, and for how many of those was `isDirectory()` true? In other words, have you considered debugging your code?

Comment: @EJP there are total 10 elements in locationfolders and all are directories and I have debuged my code and I found after looping  Location1 folder, FTPFile[] subfiles = ftpClient.listFiles(subFolder,filter); gives empty array i.e.[ ]

Comment: Which means the other directories are all empty of files that pass your filter.

Comment: @EJP but in other directories download.txt file present...trust me

Comment: Did you try the full download code as suggested above? Or can you show us FTP server log file (or FTP session capture, e.g. using Wireshark) of your code?